# Does if statement in after insert trigger matters for the performance in SQL Server? How if statement can be used for value validation?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm new to SQL Server, currently taking courses. My question is entirely for educational purposes.

I have an online artshop which includes following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE artproducts 
(
    prodid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1,1),
    catkey INT,
    prodname VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    unitprice NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
    stocknumbers INT NOT NULL,
    available CHAR(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Yes',
    FOREIGN KEY(catkey) REFERENCES artcategory(catid)
);

CREATE INDEX idx_name ON artproducts(prodname);

INSERT INTO artproducts(catkey, prodname, unitprice, stocknumbers, available)
VALUES (3, 'Autumn landscape', 150, 2, 'Yes'),
       (2, 'Brushes 5 stack', 15.95, 20, 'Yes'),
       (2, 'Canvas 100x200', 40.50, 30, 'Yes'),
       (1, 'Christmas ornament', 1.95, 30, 'Yes'),
       (4, 'Copper carafe from Byzantium', 250.99, 3, 'Yes');

CREATE TABLE artorders 
(
    orderid INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
    orderdate DATE NOT NULL,
    prodkey INT NOT NULL,
    custkey INT NOT NULL,
    quantity INT NOT NULL,
    orderprice NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
    orderstatus VARCHAR(15) DEFAULT 'In progress',
    FOREIGN KEY (prodkey) REFERENCES artproducts (prodid),
    FOREIGN KEY (custkey) REFERENCES artcustomers (custid)
);
```

I created a trigger in SQL Server 2019 to update the price in `artorders` with the price from `artproducts`:

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_artshop_FIU_checkprice
ON artorders
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    
    UPDATE artorders
    SET orderprice = prod.unitprice
    FROM artproducts AS prod
    INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON prod.prodid = i.prodkey 
    INNER JOIN artorders AS ord ON ord.prodkey = prod.prodid
END;
```

I tried to do it with if condition - to update the orderprice only when it is different from the one in artproducts. I tried using variables and subqueries, but then the trigger works only for single insert.

```
ALTER TRIGGER tr_artshop_FIU_checkprice
ON artorders
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS

BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @v_price NUMERIC (10,2);
    DECLARE @ord_price NUMERIC (10,2);

    SET @v_price = (SELECT prod.unitprice FROM artproducts AS prod INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON prod.prodid = i.prodkey)         
                        
    
    SET @ord_price = (SELECT ord.orderprice FROM artorders AS ord INNER JOIN inserted AS i ON ord.orderid = i.orderid)
            
    
    IF @ord_price != @v_price
    BEGIN   
      UPDATE artorders
      SET orderprice = prod.unitprice
      FROM artproducts AS prod
      INNER JOIN inserted AS i
      ON prod.prodid = i.prodkey 
      INNER JOIN artorders AS ord
      ON ord.prodkey = prod.prodid 
    END
    
END;
```

So, my question is whether it is better for performance to have if statement, or it doesn't matter?
But if it does, how can I use if condition working for multiple inserts.

Than You very much in advance!!!

Comment: **Warning:** your trigger is fatally flawed. It *assumes* a DML statement will only ever contain 1 row; this is simply not true.

Comment: Hi. Instead of fetching each price in separate `SELECT` statements, just combine them into one with your `UPDATE`. It will allow to use that for all rows at once.

Comment: @Larnu Interesting, I didn't know you could use the actual table name in the `UPDATE` instead of the alias, but just tested and it works! Docs say `If the object being updated is the same as the object in the FROM clause and there is only one reference to the object in the FROM clause, an object alias may or may not be specified. If the object being updated appears more than one time in the FROM clause, one, and only one, reference to the object must not specify a table alias. All other references to the object in the FROM clause must include an object alias.`

Answer (score 1):

It is better for "performance" to not have hidden bugs in your code.

The version with `IF` is assuming that `inserted` has only one row.  This is a false assumption.  In SQL Server, triggers are *set-based*.  This code is broken -- and I really wish SQL Server could find a way to return a syntax error in this case.

Hence, performance has nothing to do with why the first version is better.  In practice, I would expect the performance to be better too -- in the cases where the second doesn't generate an error (of the form: scalar subquery returned more than one row).

Comment: *"and I really wish SQL Server could find a way to return a syntax error in this case."* For the method the OP has used, it *will* error. As for methods like `select @variable = column from ManyRows;` it's well documented that the last rows value will be one the variable ends up with.

Comment: @Larnu . . . A "syntax error" or a "run-time" error.  There is a difference.

Comment: I personally don't think SQL Server should be inferring the intent of the user; that leads to madness.

Comment: Agreed with @Larnu and you IMO any query plan with an Assert is fundamentally a bug (you get Assert for single row on scalar subqueries) and should be a compile error. Define your intent: if you want one row then `select top 1` or `exists`, if not then aggregate. I'm thinking to make an Agent Job to periodically scan query store for Asserts.